# Generate Random String/letter in Scala

Tags: scala, random

I'm trying to generate a random String, and these are the possibilities I've found:

1. `Random.nextPrintableChar()`, which prints letters, numbers, punctuation
2. `Random.alphanumeric.take(size).mkString`, which prints letters and numbers
3. `Random.nextString(1)`, which prints Chinese chars almost every time lol

> Random is scala.util.Random
>
> `size` is an Int

The second option almost does the job, but I need to start with a letter. I found `Random.nextPrintableChar()` but it also prints punctuation.

What's the solution?

My solution so far was:

```
val low = 65 // A
val high = 90 // Z

((Random.nextInt(high - low) + low).toChar
```

Inspired by `Random.nextPrintableChar` implementation:

```
def nextPrintableChar(): Char = {
    val low  = 33
    val high = 127
    (self.nextInt(high - low) + low).toChar
  }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found a better solution:

`Random.alphanumeric.filter(_.isLetter).head`

A better solution as [jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665566/generate-random-string-letter-in-scala/34665585#comment57078070_34665585): `Random.alphanumeric.dropWhile(_.isDigit)`

Comment: Or, if all you need is for it to start with a letter: `Random.alphanumeric.dropWhile(_.isDigit)`

Comment: even better solution @jwvh :)

Comment: And if you need something like a 3 digit number

`Random.alphanumeric.filter(_.isDigit).take(3).mkString`

Answer (score 5):

For better control of the contents, select the alphabet yourself:

```
val alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
def randStr(n:Int) = (1 to n).map(_ => alpha(Random.nextInt(alpha.length))).mkString
```

Comment: honestly, i don't really like that approach

Comment: `(1 to n).map(_ => alpha(Random.nextInt(alpha.length))).mkString`

Comment: `Random.nextInt.abs` sometimes returns a negative value, resulting in a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for this snippet. See docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int- for more details. In the `.map`, use this instead: `_ => alpha(Random.nextInt(size))`

Comment: @RuurtjanPul As per scala doc, it should never return negative value https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/Int.html#abs:Int

Comment: Then I'm afraid the docs are incorrect. Try `Int.MinValue.abs`.

Comment: Nice catch. `Int.MinValue` is the only time this happens; one of the weirdness of using two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the fastest method to generate Random ASCII String is the following

```
  val rand = new Random()
  val Alphanumeric = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".getBytes
  
  def mkStr(chars: Array[Byte], length: Int): String = {
    val bytes = new Array[Byte](length)
    for (i <- 0 until length) bytes(i) = chars(rand.nextInt(chars.length))
    new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)
  }
  def nextAlphanumeric(length: Int): String = mkStr(Alphanumeric, length)
```